# IE8 - CSS overflow hidden, fix causes further problems with jquery

Tags: css, internet-explorer, jquery-ui, overflow, position

**Problem part 1:** Basically I have the age-old IE problem of overflow: hidden; not working in IE.  The fix (which does work, admittedly) is to also add "position: relative;" to the element/parent; however this causes a problem for me.  Firstly I want to know if there's another way without appending position relative.

If this is the only solution though, I'll outline the problem it causes:

**Problem part 1b:** I'm using jquery 1.4.2 and jquery ui 1.8.4.  The concept is basically for the user to pick up a card (draggable li item) from the pile (ul surrounded by div) and place it into the appropriate category (initially empty ul items).  Because positioning each card on top one another in the pile with css with position: absolute; would cause problems with the interaction, I've let them all display one after eachother in a column and used a div of set height and width with overflow: hidden to obscure the rest of the cards instead.  Works great in FF, but in IE doesn't work due to the overflow: hidden bug.  If I put in position: relative, for both browsers the z-index of the card when it is dragged appears to be behind everything outside of its parent div.  I've tried changing the z-index on every element on the page to specify the order, but this appears to be disregarded entirely.  I'm really hoping not to have to get into the jquery to make changes.  Any solutions?

Attached are pics which make this wall of text a little clearer.  Picture 1 is how it should work and does in FF without position relative.  Picture 2 is when position relative is added to the mix.  Both pictures show a card being dragged to a position in a new column.

Picture 1: http://plldd.net.au/storage/overflowhidden.jpg
Picture 2 is at the same location and is called positionrelative.jpg

Thanks for any help you can offer.

Answer (score 1):

can you try wrapping it all in another div with position relative? This div surrounding everything instead of the immediate parent.